# how to know who start a Linux kernel module

Tags: linux, kernel, systemd, kernel-module

There is a running kernel module (netns_vrf) in my Linux computer, like this:

```
$ lsmod | grep vrf
netns_vrf               8388  0
```

This kernel module is not from Linux distribution, it is from a third party vendor, I will not say its name here.

```
$ modinfo netns_vrf
filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.96-pc64-distro.git-17.11.2-rcp1/net/netns-vrf.ko
author:         <SOME COMPANY NAME>
license:        GPL
depends:
vermagic:       4.4.96-pc64-distro.git-17.11.2-rcp1 SMP mod_unload
```

My Linux was started by systemd, is there a way to know which systemd server insert this kernel module? I have googled a while, but could not find the answer.

**Updated**: "google" my system, and find out the script who insert the kernel module.

```
#cd /usr
#sudo grep -R netns_vrf * 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: Did you "google" your system, too? Some script should be referencing it, then pull the thread.

Comment: Thanks Ivan, now I find the script to insert the kernel module.

Comment: You should specify the distribution (various distributions have various methods to see "ownership"). Additionally, this question is more suitable in unix.SE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Google" my system, and find out the script who insert the kernel module.
Thanks to ivan_pozdeev's comments.

```
#cd /usr
#sudo grep -R netns_vrf * 2>/dev/null
```